# Copy and replace file recursively

Tags: linux, recursion

I try to find a way to copy and replace files recursively.

**Example:**

Folder `/home/test/`

```
1/test.jpg
1/sth_other.png

2/test.jpg
2/sth_other.jpg

3/test.jpg
4/test.jpg
```

You can see that in folder /home/test I have more and more folders (1,2,3,4) which file name 'test.jpg'.

I have a file /home/test.jpg

**Question:**

How to replace file 'test.jpg' in 1/2/3/4(folders) with file **/home/test.jpg** ?

Comment: `for i in \`seq 1 4\`; do cp -i /home/test.jpg /home/test/$i/test.jpg; done`, remove the -i if you are certain.

Comment: Okey but If the folders name are not next numbers, and are for ex. 'x' 'xyz' 'next' 'etc' , I thought about command 'find'

Comment: `find /home/test -name test.jpg -exec cp /home/test.jpg {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With find, you could do:

```
find /where -name test.jpg -type f -exec cp -i /home/test.jpg {} \;
```

Comment: @alain True, you need to add `-maxdepth  n` to limit the number of levels you want to search, thanks for the comment.